# can't fetch the go language repository on Debian

Tags: repository, go

I follow the installation guide at http://golang.org/doc/install.html, 
at first everything goes well, but problem comes at the "fetch the repository" step,

the guide says "$ hg clone -u release https://go.googlecode.com/hg/ go"
I follow the command but system always say that's wrong
so I read the help and modified it into 
"$ hg clone -U release ..repo url... go"
(I don't see a lowercase u option but there's a U instead which means noupdate)
but still goes wrong
so I modified it again 
"$ hg clone -U r60 ..repo url... go"
(I think release actually means go release number?)
ok, now that works finally 
but, when it's over
cd to the go directory,hey,why all the files are hidden?!
and different with the url directory, for ex there's no such a src directory

so what am I doing wrong, and sorry for my english is not good
thank you for your help

---

### for as a new user I can't attach a image and can't have more than two links in one post, see the picture link below at the reply to Evan Shaw

and in the guide page they say that I need to install python-setuptools python-dev and build-essential, because in ubuntu/debian users' distribution's package repository, the  will "most likely be old and broken", what that mean? Am I suppose to install the tool manually(but not a easy_install)?

---

### for a new user I can't answer myself,I think jnml points out the best matched answer

I thought this question is answerd,
the problem is that repository in Ubuntu/Debian for  is tool old,
if you just easy_install  (apt-get install ) 
you got version 1.0.1 , that's not match for the command gave on the go installation guide,
so a simple way to work it out is(thanks jnml for pointing this out):

1. hg clone
2. cd go
3. hg update release

that's done.

but I still wonder how can I get the latest version of  be installed on my Debian,but that's another question,

### Thanks a lot to all of you who reply to me, thank you for your help!

Comment: Can you please post the error message you're getting? If I copy the exact command as is and run it, it works for me. That command is: `hg clone -u release https://go.googlecode.com/hg/ go`

Comment: thank you for your reply, what is your operation system version? Mine is debian lenny 5.0.9 amd x64 , and the error message is just say that is a unrecognized opion, you can check the screen capture here https://lh6.googleusercontent.com/-u_divPm2jyE/TxKhyaA-GQI/AAAAAAAAE2c/ZT9baoVj1Kw/s800/errormsg.jpg

Comment: You can also try just the `hg clone` part and afterwards `hg update release` (or weekly).

Comment: to jnml, yeah, with your suggestion, I got it, it's the mercurial version problem, but how can I install the latest version of mercurial? .. oh, maybe this is a new quesion LOL, anyway, thank you

Answer (score 1, accepted):

hg -u (lower case) is definitely correct, check your version of mercurial.

```
$ hg help clone
...
options:

 -U --noupdate           the clone will include an empty working copy (only a repository)
 -u --updaterev REV      revision, tag or branch to check out
...
$
```

Comment: Hi,thank you for your reply, the version of mercurial is 1.0.1, I remove it with "apt-get autoremove mercurial" and made a apt-get update, then "apt-get install mercurial" again, but sitll that version ,and I check the help again, there's no the lower case u option, so what is the latest version of mercurial and how can install the latest one? thank you agian

Comment: I'm running `Mercurial Distributed SCM (version 1.6.3)`, I guess 1.0.1 is too old.